# How to propose alteration of study subjects in college?

Tags: teaching, university, course-evaluation

I've been studying and working with Game Development for quite a while and I can't help to notice that I'm not using **anything** that was presented to me in college.

My college is focused in gaming programming, **BUT** all that is taught is basic programming like basic loops, conditions or object oriented programming. Most of the teachers don't even know how to build a game or what a game engine is.

I believe it's taught this way because there's no teacher with experience in the area and the topics are very wide, like "programming class" without specifying a programming language and what's going to be learned.

Is there a way I could propose a change of the subjects we study in class? Or even bring attention to the matter, so that someone could take action?

Comment: Do you still keep in touch with any of your old profs? You could drop them a nice email and mention new methods you use. Or, you could offer to give a seminar or guest lecture for your profs. Another option would be to speak for a student group (e.g., a student SIAM chapter).

Comment: Are you still in that college, or are you well past it?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand the question - is it that you're now teaching at a college and they are making you teach a syllabus which you don't think is suitable or that you're studying at a new college and it's not as good as your previous one?

Comment: See [Approach the professors about making the course more “relevant”](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/19139/approach-the-professors-about-making-the-course-more-relevant)

Comment: You might want to compare your school's program of study with that of another school with a strong program in your field, and then contact the accrediting body.

Comment: Needs more detail: Are you a current student, ex-student, something else? When you say "working with Game Development" are you talking about: class assignments, hobby work, or professional work?

Comment: @RichardErickson there are my current teachers.

Comment: @svavil still in the college

Comment: @Retro actually I dont agree with the content teacher are teaching in my current college

Comment: Can you more specifically describe what work you're doing: It sounds like you're using a prepackaged game engine. What engine is it? What work are you doing with it? How large is the team that you're working with? Have they successfully shipped a product in the past?

Comment: @DanielR.Collins yep, we use Unity Engine (which btw is free for academic use), we use it to put all together (sound, models, etc) and program the game and its dependences, the team is not large, about 6 people, yep they succeeded in inumerous projects.

Comment: I'll ask again: "What work are **you** doing with it?" Are you creating graphics? 3D models? Scripts? Shaders? Testing? Programming?

Comment: @DanielR.Collins ohhh ok, didn't get it that way, well Im programming it

Comment: This is very hard to parse. You say in the question "I'm not using anything that was presented to me in college.... all that is taught is basic programming like basic loops, conditions or object oriented programming." But now you say that you are programming. Are you scripting gameplay in C#, or Javascript, or do you mean something else?

Comment: @DanielR.Collins Im using C# and yeah, im using basic loops and conditions in the coding that is needed, but 99% of the coding in the game demands knowledge a little bit deeper then normal business programming. I feel that in college teachers focuses too much in the normal business programming and in diferent programming languages that have just some details that makes em different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comments, you explained that you are currently a student. I would suggest you have a friendly conversation with your professors. Perhaps you know your advisor a little bit, or one of your professors from your class and you're comfortable talking to her or him.

For example, let's say you decide to talk with Professor Smith. I would go up to Professor Smith (e.g., during office hours) and say: "Hi. I had a cool internship at Gaming, Inc. I learned some interesting programing methods X, Y, and Z" (follow their interest in their methods here, you might end up deep in details or your professor may not care). Then ask something like "We haven't covered the methods in my classes. I think they would help other students in our program. Are they included anywhere in our curriculum?"

This will start a conversation with your Professor about the curriculum. Most reasonable professor will be open to your conversation, just don't put them on the defensive. For example, avoid saying something like "our program sucks..." or "you *should* do...". Also, keep your suggestions positive and avoid being arrogant. Perhaps your program is revising their curriculum now and you do not know about it.

As an aside, I had a similar experience as an undergrad wildlife biology student. During a summer internship, I worked for a government agency using management approaches not covered in class. I asked a friendly professor why we were not learning the topic during an informal office hour. The friendly prof said a couple of reasons (basically their curriculum had not been updated) and then another, crotchety old professor jumped in and though my idea was stupid (he was dinosaur who did not like change). The friendly professor actually changed his view point and started defending my question/view-point. In my case, I was not able to change the curriculum, but I did learn why it was what it was.